# Public vars/methods on controller not seen as defined by Jasmine running through Chutzpah

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, chutzpah

I'm trying to run Jasmine tests on my Angular app using Chutzpah in Visual Studio.

I have a controller that is defined as:

```
angular.module('testApp')
.controller('TestAppCtrl', ['TestService',
    function ($service) {
        var vm = this;

        // just a function for testing
        vm.sum = function (x, y) { return x + y };
    }
]);
```

I then describe my Jasmine test as:

```
describe('TestAppCtrl', function () {
    var ctrl, TestService;

    beforeEach(module('testApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, _TestService_) {
        TestService= _TestService_;
        ctrl = $controller('TestAppCtrl');
    }));

    it('ctrl is defined', function () {
        expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('1 + 2 equals 3', function () {
        expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
        expect(ctrl.sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
    });
});
```

The second test, `1 + 2 equals 3`, fails. I get this error:

```
Message: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'ctrl.sum(1, 2)') in file:///...
```

I've tried this in varying ways: defining a simple variable on the controller (`vm.testVar = 12345`), or even by injecting the `$scope` and defining variables on that. I correctly injected it on the test as well. Both of these attempts failed in the same error; it's as though the test runner doesn't recognize any values on the controller, even though the controller itself is defined.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this should work...
But try calling the $controller() function with a second argument that is the scope, as seen in this example: [How to test John papa vm.model unit testing with jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456747/how-to-test-john-papa-vm-model-unit-testing-with-jasmine)

Maybe that has an influence on how the scope is created...